# Output vaule using odeint

Tags: python, scipy, ode, odeint

I have a defined system of differential equations called iron, time t in the range (0, 1000), with a time step of 100. Then I want to generate solutions for subsequent sets of parameters defined as the variable vals. As a result, I get a matrix with 4 columns that has solutions in rows for each set of parameters from vals. The function used to solve the equation is an odeint from the SciPy library. My question is whether the obtained results are the average of the given time interval for a given solution, or are they from a specific point in time, for example, from the last moment of time?

```
for i in range(len(vals)):
  Y[i][:] = sp.odeint(iron, XYZ0, t, args=tuple(vals[i]))[-1]
```

Comment: Is the description of the return value in the [docstring](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) not clear?

" **y : array, shape (len(t), len(y0))**

    Array containing the value of y for each desired time in t, with the initial value y0 in the first row."